# How to group by a column and get a mean of freashest n records?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I've a date frame with a structure

```
Date          value type
2015-01-01    1     2
2015-01-02    2     3
2015-01-03    1     2
2015-01-03    4     3
2015-01-05    7     5
```

the dateframe has an index over 'Date' column.
I need to get a mean of n most fresh records per each 'type'. Or rolling mean per each type(for me it looks like more sophisticated task, but might be it's easy to implement).
How can I make that query in most efficient way? Looping per 'type' is really slow.

I'm ok with creation a temporary date structure if it will speed up the query.

Comment: Please provide the dataframe with index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is sorted by `date`, you can write a aggregate function to do this:

```
In [22]:
#simply made your dataframe larger to have more than 2 items per group
print df

         Date  value  type
0  2015-01-01      1     2
1  2015-01-02      2     3
2  2015-01-03      1     2
3  2015-01-03      4     3
4  2015-01-05      7     5
5  2015-01-06      1     2
6  2015-01-07      2     3
7  2015-01-08      1     2
8  2015-01-09      4     3
9  2015-01-10      7     5

In [23]:

df.groupby(['type']).value.agg(lambda x: np.mean(x[-2:])) #2 newest observations

Out[23]:

type
2    1
3    3
5    7
Name: value, dtype: int64
```